# How to only pull the most recent row of multiple timestamp duplications

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query my database to obtain future timestamp predictions illustrated in the column 'RRP'. The future timestamps are represented by the 'INTERVAL_DATETIME' column. Where my current query is as follows:

```
select `RUN_DATETIME`, `INTERVAL_DATETIME`, `REGIONID`, `RRP`
from mms.p5min_regionsolution
where REGIONID = 'SA1'
order by INTERVAL_DATETIME desc limit 100
```

However, as you can see in the figure below, there are usually multiple duplications of the INTERVAL_DATETIME column and consequently the RRP column. How can I edit my query so that I only get the most recent duplication of the INTERVAL_DATETIME column and RRP and disregard the others. I have also included the RUN_DATETIME column if this can be used in any way.
[image: Database layout]

Comment: @astentx, not really unfortunately, in that question they had an additional column with a group ID, I only have the timestamps column which is dynamically updating in comparison to a static group ID.

Comment: You need first (top 1) record per timestamp (grouped results), so `row_number() over(partition by <other cols>, interval_datetime order by run_datetime desc)`. Or I didn't get the logic.

Comment: How about distinct?

Comment: what does `select version();` say?